# Custom UITableViewCells Reloading Issue

Tags: xcode, uitableview, custom-cell

Whenever I delete a cell the cell that was previously in its place imageViews don't disappear. 
For example a cell uses all three image views, and was deleted and replaced by a cell that one used one of the image views. The two images views with the images of the previous cell (Which was deleted) remain. 
When I delete a cell I remove the object from an nsmutablearray and do reloadData on the uitableview.

I made a custom uitableviewcell which looks like

```
@interface MyPetTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet PetNameLabel *petName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageOne;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageTwo;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageThree;

@end
```

My UITableView is setup like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PetCell";
    MyPetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    PetResponse *petItem = self.petListResponse.PetList[indexPath.row];
    NSString *petNameItem = petItem.PetName;
    NSLog(@"PET NAME : %@",petNameItem);
    NSLog(@"NUMBER OF IMAGES : %lu", (unsigned long)petItem.EncodedImages.count);
    for (int i = 0; i < [petItem.EncodedImages count]; i++) {

        NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:petItem.EncodedImages[i] options:0];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedData];
        if (i == 0) {
            cell.imageOne.image = image;
        } else if (i == 1)
        {
            cell.imageTwo.image = image;
        } else if (i == 2)
        {
            cell.imageThree.image = image;
        }
    }
    cell.petName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ :",petNameItem];
    UIColor *customcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:11/255.0f green:64/255.0f blue:64/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
    cell.petName.backgroundColor = customcolor;
    cell.petName.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cell.petName.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.petName sizeToFit];

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    NSLog(@"Returning Cell");
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show your delete cell code also..how you are removing object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to guess what happens, but one possibility is the following:
Table view cells are re-used. So when  you add, e.g., a subview to a table view cell, and the corresponding row of the table view is scrolled out of the screen, the cell (with the subviews!) is put back into the re-use pool. If a new table row should be shown, chances are that the now unused cell (with the old subviews) is taken from the re-use pool, and the old subviews will be shown.
What could you do in this case is to "prepare a table view cell for re-use", using the method

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
```

In this method, you could remove all old subviews, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW33).

Comment: From your link, it says that `prepareForReuse` should only be used for cell attributes that are not related to content. tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath should be used in this case since he's changing the image content.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with cell reuse. As the apple documentation says:

> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should
>   always reset all content when reusing a cell.

One possible solution would be to set all images to `nil` before assigning the new images

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PetCell";
        MyPetTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        PetResponse *petItem = self.petListResponse.PetList[indexPath.row];
        NSString *petNameItem = petItem.PetName;
        NSLog(@"PET NAME : %@",petNameItem);
        NSLog(@"NUMBER OF IMAGES : %lu", (unsigned long)petItem.EncodedImages.count);

        cell.imageOne.image = nil;
        cell.imageTwo.image = nil;
        cell.imageThree.image = nil;

        for (int i = 0; i < [petItem.EncodedImages count]; i++) {

            NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:petItem.EncodedImages[i] options:0];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:decodedData];
            if (i == 0) {
                cell.imageOne.image = image;
            } else if (i == 1)
            {
                cell.imageTwo.image = image;
            } else if (i == 2)
            {
                cell.imageThree.image = image;
            }
        }
        cell.petName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ :",petNameItem];
        UIColor *customcolor = [UIColor colorWithRed:11/255.0f green:64/255.0f blue:64/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
        cell.petName.backgroundColor = customcolor;
        cell.petName.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        cell.petName.numberOfLines = 0;
        [cell.petName sizeToFit];

        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        NSLog(@"Returning Cell");
        return cell;
    }
```